# Creating a Django Chat App

Tags: ajax, django, chat

I know that there are many posts about this, but I'm still confused about the process of making a chat.

I want to make a webpage that allows users to chat with one another randomly. I looked online for the code for django-chat, django-jchat, and django-jqchat. They all seem a little confusing to me. I can't seem to make sense of how to properly modify/use them. Because of this, I kinda feel like I should make one from scratch.

Now, these chat services require that you query the mysql database with ajax, to retrieve the chat information. I feel like this would cause a large amount of querying, and thus clog up the server. I was thinking of a different method:
What if I, instead, create a textfile for every chat that takes place, and then read from that textfile any changes etc. And display the chat from that textfile? Then, I would delete the textfile when the chat is done. I feel like i wouldn't have to make ajax poll the database at all, and python is quite efficient at reading text files. Would this not work for large amounts of people? Would the mysql route be easier?

If I were to take the mysql route, what components would my model require? (sorry, newbie question).

Also, I was wondering how I can use ajax to keep watching the textfile, and printing the changes? Or would it be better to issue an ajax command that would just check the textfile every 2 seconds or so? How would I even do this? (I'm sort of new to ajax).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is known as push vs polling otherwise one approach is known as Comet.  This is not trival.  And no...saving things to a text file isn't likely to help you nor is it going to resolve the underlying issue of needing to understand push based systems